# Which preposition goes with "dawn"?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should I use to specify something happening when the sun comes up?

> - At the dawn of April 1
> - In the dawn of April 1
> - On the dawn of April 1

Comment: none of the above: I would say "**At** dawn **on** April 1st..."

Comment: You can use "At the dawn..." too.  It's a more formal tone reminiscent of the intro to War of the Worlds and probably the one I'd choose.  Max's suggestion is the one to go for though, as it's a cleaner, simpler approach.

Comment: I think that if you say "At the dawn" you then need to say "of April 1st" rather than "on April 1st".  This usage tends to be used with grand events like *"At the dawn of the 21st Century"*.

Answer (score 1):

"**At** dawn **on** April 1st" suggests it's at a specific date and time, whereas "**At the** dawn **of** April 1st" suggests the beginning of April 1st without giving a specific time (e.g. "At the dawn of mankind"), so both are correct but convey a different message.

The right way to express "when the sun comes up" is therefore the first option: "At dawn on April 1st".

Comment: Alternatively, you could say: "On April 1st, at dawn."

Comment: "**In** the dawn of April 1st" might be used, albeit in a literary tone, to describe events that took place under the conditions of first light.  E.g., "The villagers slept, as Boltar's soldiers crept forward *in the dawn*."